# add a many_to_many participation model to two existing table with one_to_many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, has-many-through, belongs-to

ok, this is my situation, i have two existing models, User and Event, which have a one_to_many association:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :events
...
end
```

and in my event class i have:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
...
end
```

i did this in order to associate a `user_id` with an event as its creator.
so now i want to add a third table called `event_participation`, what is the best way to do that?
and how can i add a fourth model called `event_invitation`?

Answer (score 0):

Use source

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
     has_many :events
     has_many :my_events, through: :event_participation, source: event
end
```

Comment: ok thanks, and the same logic applies for event_invitation? saying because it's a self_referencing association